# Find Minimum Value Based on 2 Criteria (Excel 2013)

Tags: excel, vba

Looking to find the max value in a column based on two sets of criteria

So the logic would be: Find the minimum value in column M, where the value in column A matches column N, and the value in Column Y is less than 318.

I've tried using an array formula like this but it doesn't seem to be working/is to memory heavy to run:
=MIN(IF(AND(N:N=A2,Y:Y<=318),M:M))

is there a simpler way?  or perhaps a UDF that could work?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `AND` in these type of formulas because it only returns a single value rather than the required array.

Here are three possible working versions:

1.) Use * to simulate `AND`

`=MIN(IF((N:N=A2)*(Y:Y<=318),M:M))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

2.) Use multiple nested IFs

`=MIN(IF(N:N=A2,IF(Y:Y<=318,M:M)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

3.) Use `AGGREGATE` function

`=AGGREGATE(15,6,M:M/(N:N=A2)/(Y:Y<=318),1)`

The advantages of this approach are that you don't need "array entry", and it can ignore any errors in the data

Either way it's best to reduce the ranges sizes if you can because it might be slow with whole columns

Comment: Hi Barry -- first time seeing the aggregate function.  Can you explain how it works?

Comment: AGGREGATE is a little like SUBTOTAL function - the first number dictates the "function", e.g. SUM, AVERAGE, MIN etc. Although there is a MIN option you can't use that with conditions (because it doesn't accept an array) so 15 represents SMALL function, 6 tells Excel to ignore errors and then the `M:M/(N:N=A2)/(Y:Y<=318)` part creates an array which will either return errors or numbers (only when your conditions are met)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try and adjust ranges to suit.  Try not to use whole column references:

```
=SMALL(INDEX(($N$2:$N$101=A2)*($Y$2:$Y$101<=318)*$M$2:$M$101,),1+ROWS($M$2:$M$101)-COUNTIFS($N$2:$N$101,A2,$Y$2:$Y$101,"<=318"))
```

If you are using the whole column to pick up new data as it is added, consider using [Dynamic Named Ranges](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html#Dynamic) instead

Answer (score 0):

When things get this complex, I'll usually break it down and setup smaller/simpler formulas in seperate columns.

In other words, you have data in columns A through Y ?

So let's create a formula in column AA:
1) identify when value in Col A matches col N, and value in col Y < 318

```
=and(A1=N1,Y1<318)
```

2) copy AA1 to all the rows of your data.

3) now we have a condition to work off .. since there is a SUMIF and COUNTIF, but no MINIF .. we'll have to build that ourselves. first the IF:
in column AB1:

```
=if(AA1,M1,"")
```

copy that down to all your data.

finally, do your min:

```
=MIN(AB:AB)
```

Should give you your answer.

You could probably splice the first two together, but again, building a complex formula like this, build it simply, first, ;)